# How big is a baby's stomach?

Tags: nutrition

There is a lot of contradictory information on baby feeding volumes on the internet. A common claim is that a baby's stomach is the size of a hazelnut or small marble, with a volume of 5-7 ml. But this seems confusing on two counts -

1. Breast milk contains approximately 0.7 cal per ml, so feeding 6 ml eight times per day would only provide the baby with 33 calories, which doesn't seem enough.
2. A typical marble is 1/2 inch (1.25 cm) in diameter, which means it has a volume of about 1 ml, not 5-7 ml as claimed.

Are there any authoritative sources on the size of a baby's stomach?

Comment: I am voting to have this migrated to biology.se

Comment: At 1 month it's 80-150 mL. https://www.lllc.ca/thursday-tip-newborns-have-small-stomachs

Comment: That site does not look particularly authoritative...

Comment: @Chris Very happy to have this migrated to biology.se if that's the most appropriate place for it

Comment: I am migrating this, they may ask for specifics on age of child. I also removed the "how much can they eat", as that is highly variable by bebby.

Answer (score 4):

The first 30 days involve rapid growth, but generally, fall within a standard proximal range of 5 - 7mL on day one. By day 3 the stomach has expanded vastly to nearly 23 - 27 mL. From this point on, growth and size to age ratio will vary a bit.

https://themomivist.com/2016/10/10/the-newborn-stomach-size-myth-it-is-not-5-7ml/

Here's a link to an article that has some efficacy. Many hospitals and physicians use different techniques and believe differently on this particular subject. Considering the laws surrounding experimentation on fetus and children, the "Size" of the stomach debate only has efficacy if we were able to case study THOUSANDS of infant stomachs which isn't likely to happen anytime soon. I hope the link helps and maybe points you in the right direction. There really is no 100% correct way to answer this as the studies surrounding it just don't have any weight to them.

Answer (score 4):

Infant stomach capacity:

- At birth: 5-35 mL
- 1 week - 1 month: 60-120 mL
- 6-12 months: 210-240 mL

Sources:

- http://alabamapublichealth.gov/Staging/test/perinatal/assets/StomachCapacity.pdf
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23662739
- http://www.dhss.delaware.gov/dph/chs/files/neurobehavioralapproach.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the human uterus is about the size of a fist.  That doesn't mean it can't be stretched.  Plenty of babies are perfectly capable of eating and holding down an oz of formula shortly after birth.

This overview of the research says between 10 mL and 30 mL

http://www.infantmentalhealth.co.za/files/Bergman_2013_stomach_capacity_feed_interval.pdf